# formArray in a tbody with only one colum to be validated

Tags: angular

I'm having a hard time using [formArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray). We have a **list** of a class:

```
class item {
    value: number;
    name: string
    status: string
}
```

Only the property **value** should be validated and is bounded to an input field.

We managed to display the readonly properties (I don't know if this is the correct way to do this tho).

We didn't manage to bind the input field (the samples I found they don't use **ngModel**, so I'm avoiding it)

We also don't know how to add the validation only for the **value** property.

So here are my questions:

1. How to bind properly the readonly fields?
2. How to bind the input field without **ngModel**?
3. How to create validation for the **value** property only?

That is our **HTML**:

```
<div [formGroup]="parentForm">
  <div *ngIf="items">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Value</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody formArrayName="itemsForm">
        <tr *ngFor="let item of parentForm.controls.itemsForm.controls; let i=index">
          <td><span>{{ item.value.name }}</span></td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" [formControlName]="i" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" /> <!--How do I show the value here?-->
          </td>
          <td>
            <app-status [status]="item.value.status"></app-status>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

That is how we bind our form:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {

    let controls = new Array<FormControl>();

    this.items.forEach((item) => controls.push(new FormControl(item)));

    this.parentForm.addControl("itemsForm", new FormArray(controls));

    console.log(this.parentForm);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to use nested form groups inside the form array. I like to inject formbuilder in constructor, here in this sample I refer to it with `fb`.

So build your form...

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.parentForm = this.fb.group({
    itemsForm: this.fb.array([])
  });
  // add below to the callback instead after you have received your data!
  this.populateForm();
}
```

and the `populateForm`:

```ts
populateForm() {
  const control = <FormArray>this.parentForm.controls['itemsForm'];
  // the data you have received, for each object create a form group
  this.items.forEach(item => {
    control.push(this.initItems(item))
  })
}

initItems(item) {
  // create a formgroup for each item
  return this.fb.group({
    value: [item.value, Validators.required], // set required or whatever else
    name: [item.name] 
    status: [item.status]
  })
}
```

Then in your view iterate this formarray and display input field for `value` and the others can be shown just as plain text:

```html
....
<tbody formArrayName="itemsForm">
  <tr *ngFor="let item of parentForm.controls.itemsForm.controls; let i = index" >
    <ng-container formGroupName="{{i}}">
       <td><input formControlName="value" /></td>
       <td>Name: {{item.value.name}}</td>
       <td>Status: {{item.value.status}}</td>
    </ng-container>
  </tr>
</tbody>
....
```

You'd also perhaps want to actually use variables, to which you assign the different form control "paths" and not use e.g... `parentForm.controls.itemsForm.controls` but that is just a suggestion :)

Comment: Yeah I see that now, updated template a bit also using `ng-container`. Realizing you have the status in a child component, but the above works, so there shouldn't be a problem to do change that detail :)

Comment: amazing. I was looking for hours for an answer like that here on the web!!!

Comment: You are very welcome, glad to hear it worked out!! :)

Comment: it worked just like a charm :) only thing is that I have multiple instances of this tbody and all the instances are now with the same values althought they have different data sources.  I would appreciate if you had any clue how to solve this...

Comment: I just realized the instances are using the same "itemsForm" formArrayName and that's why, so I need to find a way to nake this name dynamic. Any good practice?

Comment: problem solved, thanks. All working good now :) I just had to instantiate FormArray!

Comment: Haha, okay, I was already scratching my head to figure out what you really mean, since it's hard to picture this without seeing the code further, but well done, you figured it out yourself :D Have a good one and happy coding!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148304/discussion-between-dag-and-ajt-82).

Answer (score 1):

Use `FromGroup`s, `Validators` and `FormBuilder` to do that :

```
myForm: FormGroup;
constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        name: '', // Put the default value here
        status: '',
        value: [0, Validators.required] // Or any Validator you would use
    });
}
```

In your HTML

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="yourSubmitFunction" [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="value" required>
    <!-- and other inputs -->
    <!-- remember to match the validators ! (e.g. required tag for required validator) -->
</form>
```

**EDIT** About the readonly fields, just don't send them on your submit function

Comment: what about the formArray? How do I map it with my array from backend?

Comment: The form array is used to display array values. let's say that you have an User that has one name, but several addresses : name is a simple form control, while address is a form array. Given your object structure, you don't need a form array, since all you have is number and string.

Comment: sorry, I don't know if have read my post exactly, but I need a form array for iteration, I have a tbody with *ngFor where I have an input field

Comment: So *ngFor will repeat your input. As I told you, formArray is only used to input array values. You don't have array values, so you don't need formArrays. But what you're doing is a bit nasty to me : you create a form and iterate over its controls ? Why not, instead, create a form that is based on your actual model ?

Comment: I'll give it a shot, it's my first time building Angular 4 forms. This sample with iteration through controls comes from a book actually...

Comment: Well it is too generic, here you have a specific case, you should adapt to it. Maybe you could read the official Angular documentation to help you too, they made a very great guide for reactive forms.

Comment: I read the documentation several times, I don't see anything relevant to my case...(I have nested formGroup because of parent components)

Comment: What is your case exactly : you get one object out of the database, and you would like to make a form ? Or you get an array of objects from it ? or you want to make a generic component ? Describe it specificly, it will be easier for me to help you

Comment: I described, it's a List, an Array. it comes from the database as a list...I posted in my post in bold actually :)

Comment: That's not enough to help me but nevermind. If I only rely on your post, then a simple *ngFor with my solution is enough.