# How to handle two instances of formArrayName / formGroupName?

Tags: angular

Based on this thread: [formArray in a tbody with only one colum to be validated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901983/formarray-in-a-tbody-with-only-one-colum-to-be-validated/44903203?noredirect=1#comment76784893_44903203) I managed to show my grid properly with the values. The problem is, if I have the same instance of this grid on the same page, the values of the first grid are displayed in the second grid. I assume this is the expected behavior as they have the same **formGroupName** and same **formArrayName**.

You can check the bahavior here: http://recordit.co/HxuFJpVRQP

That is my HTML:

```
  <tbody *ngIf="editMode" formArrayName="itemsForm">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of parentForm.controls.itemsForm.controls; let i = index" >
      <ng-container formGroupName="{{i}}">
        <td><span>{{ item.value.categoryName }}</span></td>
        <td><input type="number" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" formControlName="value" /></td>
        <td>
          <app-status [status]="item.value.status"></app-status>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

That is my TypeScript:

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createForm();
  }

  private createForm(): void {
    let controls = new FormArray([]);

    // the data you have received, for each object create a form group
    this.items.forEach(item => {
      controls.push(new FormGroup(
        {
          categoryName: new FormControl(item.categoryName),
          value: new FormControl(item.value),
          status: new FormControl(item.status)
        }));
    });

    this.parentForm.addControl("itemsForm", controls);
  }
```

This all works just like a charm if I have only one grid. Do I have to give my component an Id? Is this really necessary?

**EDIT:**

I got to solve this issue by passing the **formArrayName** as an **@Input** parameter:

```
@Input() public itemsForm;

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.createForm();
}

private createForm(): void {
  let controls = new FormArray([]);

  // the data you have received, for each object create a form group
  this.items.forEach(item => {
    controls.push(new FormGroup(
    {
      categoryName: new FormControl(item.categoryName),
      value: new FormControl(item.value),
      status: new FormControl(item.status)
    }));
  });

  this.parentForm.addControl(this.itemsForm, controls);
}
```

Now in my parent component I just have to give the `itemsForm` property a different name for each instance of the child component:

```
<app-my-grid [itemsForm]="'arrayNamed1'" *ngIf="datasource1" [parentForm]="prognoseMeldungForm" [items]="datasource1" [editMode]="isEditMode"></app-my-grid>

<app-my-grid [itemsForm]="'arrayNamed2'" *ngIf="datasource2" [parentForm]="prognoseMeldungForm" [items]="datasource2" [editMode]="isEditMode"></app-my-grid>
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: why not write a custom directive with a isolated scope?

Comment: are you taking about angularjs or angular? I don't know what you mean with directive with a isolated scope